# Orchard CMS: Why Display Function in BodyPartDriver is not getting invoked after adding custom Theme?

Tags: orchardcms

I have created a Custom theme with TheThemeMachineResponsive as Base theme in orchard cms and now when I create new page it donot come to display even home page is also not coming. 
Like I have created a page and accessing it with that defined url "/my-menu-page" but its not coming to view. In old theme I never had such a problem.
Please let me know how  I can handle this issue. What should I do to make it render on site. 
I have checked in BodyPartDriver.cs the Display method is not getting invoked.
My placement.info file is empty as that of base theme.

Here is my Layout.cshtml file's main part.

```
<div id="layout-main-container">
    <div id="layout-main" class="group">
        @{
            string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        }
        @if (Model.AsideFirst != null && !(WorkContext.CurrentUser == null))
        {            
            <aside id="aside-first" class="aside-first group">
                @Zone(Model.AsideFirst)
            </aside>
        }
        <div id="layout-content" class="group">
            @if (Model.Messages != null) {
                <div id="messages">
                    @Zone(Model.Messages)
                </div>
            }
            @if (Model.BeforeContent != null) {
                <div id="before-content">
                    @Zone(Model.BeforeContent)
                </div>
            }@* the model content for the page is in the Content zone @ the default position (nothing, zero, zilch) *@
            @if (Model.Content != null)
            {
               <div id="content" class="group">
                    @Zone(Model.Content)
               </div>
            }
            @if (Model.AfterContent != null) {
                <div id="after-content">
                    @Zone(Model.AfterContent)
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        @if (Model.AsideSecond != null) {
            <aside id="aside-second" class="aside-second">
                @Zone(Model.AsideSecond)
            </aside>
        }
    </div>
</div>
@if (Model.AfterMain != null)
{
<div id="layout-after-main" class="group">
    @Zone(Model.AfterMain)
</div>
}
@if (Model.TripelFirst != null || Model.TripelSecond != null || Model.TripelThird != null)
{
<div id="layout-tripel-container">
<div id="layout-tripel" class="group">@* as in beer *@
    @if (Model.TripelFirst != null)
    {
    <div id="tripel-first">
        @Zone(Model.TripelFirst)
    </div>
    }
    @if (Model.TripelSecond != null)
    {
    <div id="tripel-second">
        @Zone(Model.TripelSecond)
    </div>
    }
    @if (Model.TripelThird != null)
    {
    <div id="tripel-third">
        @Zone(Model.TripelThird)
    </div>
    }
</div>
</div>
}
```

I will appreciate any help in this regard.
Thanks 
Sohaib

Comment: You will need to provide a little more information. Your custom theme probably isn't displaying the correct zone or have the placements correctly defined. Start by reading http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-new-theme and showing us your Layout.cshtml file

Comment: I have added layout.cshtml file please take a look. Also I have used The Theme Machine as base theme.

Comment: What I'm missing in my Layout.cshtml file? is this the problem with it?

Comment: @hazza would you please help me out

Comment: What do you see when you go to the url? A blank page? Or are you see the menu and site title etc. Have you tried any other pages? Have you checked the log files (located in Orhcard.Web/AppData/Logs)?

Comment: I can see Navigation (header menu) , side bar menu (aside first) but the page that I have created using dashboard is not coming. The rest area of the screen is empty. I have created another page to see whether it comes or not but it did not. I have checked log files and its empty.

Comment: Only widget pages are coming. i.e widgets are getting rendered only. 
Also I have overriden shape Parts.ElementWrapper-181.cshtml.

Comment: Try using shape tracing to see what is being sent into the content zone maybe

Comment: I have added a text widget in content zone from dashboard so its coming there. but All I need is a page to get displayed created from dashboard

Comment: I have overriden particular content shape is it the cause of problem?

Comment: @Hazza could you please help me out to solve this problem.. I'm unable to figure out why my display method inside bodypartdriver.cs is not getting invoked. I have created new theme and after that this is what happening to me. I have tried codeplex.com but not getting any clue. Have watched videos about orchard shapes. Could you please leave couple of comments on this? that would be really helpful for me.

Comment: The Placement.info file decides whether drivers should be run, it could be that although I don't know why your custom theme would affect this, so have a look at this page. http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info

Comment: ok thanks solved the issue finally.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Actually there was a file LayourRoot.cshtml and was empty so I wrote required line there. So all was fine after that.